# NGINX download file from another URL from the backend

Tags: url, redirect, nginx, download, hide

totally newbie for NGINX conf file regex. I am running a PHP script that runs under NGINX web server. I am trying to let the visitor download an attached file that is different from URL. For example, if the link is:

```
http://mysite.com/attachement/sample.jpg
```

it will actually serve the file from a different directory "media/uploaded"

```
http://mysite.com/media/uploaded/sample.jpg
```

based on some research, I have added something like this

```
location /attachment/ {      
    try_files $uri /media/uploaded/$uri;
}
```

But it's not working. My intention is not let the user browser redirect to the page that is viewing the URL, just download the file extensions like *.png, *.jpg, *.zip, etc. This scripted worked fine liked this in Apache, but it's not in Nginx.

Although it's not important, was wondering if it's also possible to let them download *.php, *.fla files without executing them for obvious security reasons. I remember using a support ticket system long time ago that allowed this too. Don't know if it's possible to pull it off from Nginx conf file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want them to be like an exact mirror, easiest way is to use `alias`

```
location /attachment/ {
    alias /media/uploaded;
}
```

If you want to use `try_files` then you need to specify `root`

```
location ~ /attachment/(.*) {
    root /media/uploaded;
    try_files $1 =404; # or replace '=404' with any fallback rule
}
```

Your rule didn't work probably because `$uri` already contains `/attachment` so the URL that's being tested is `/media/uploaded/attachment/image.jpg` which doesn't exist, it could be fixed using regex like I did in the second method, but that's too much work, your case is better suited for `alias`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tips. None of them worked, but was able to add more codes to do so with alias

```
location  ~ ^/attachment/([^\s]+(?=\.(jpg|gif|png|zip|))\.\2) {
    alias /home/websites/public_html/media/uploaded/$1;
}
```

getting a tip from another post (forgot where it was). Thanks!

Comment: do you have a proper `root` in your config, on the server block level ?